# JavaScript Not Showing in File

Tags: magento2, javascript

Trying to add some custom JS to my module. The file is called in the `<head>` section, but theres no code in the file called.

`/view/frontend/web/js/fitmentsearch.js`

```
define([
  "jquery"
], 
function($) {
  "use strict";

  // Here your custom code...
  console.log('Hola');

});
```

`/requirejs-config`

```
var config = {

  // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
  deps: [
    "js/fitmentsearch"
  ]

};
```

`default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="EkkoMedia_FitmentSearch::css/fitmentsearch.css" />
        <script src="EkkoMedia_FitmentSearch::js/fitmentsearch.js"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js" src_type="url" />
    </head> 
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.containertwo" as="header_containertwo" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-fitmentsearch" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="header.containertwo">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mini.container" template="EkkoMedia_FitmentSearch::test.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Comment: Where you put your js? show me your xml.

Comment: Could you show me how to your call your js file ??

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh XML added